# Typescript Symbol.species typing inference

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Let's say I have a custom `MyArray<T>` class that extends upon the builtin `Array<T>` class, how should I type so that `myMap<T>(myArr: MyArray<T>, <Function>)` can correctly infer the return type as `MyArray<T>`, instead of the builtin `Array<T>`?

PS: I want this type declaration to be as general as possible, which is why I didn't simply overload the `map` method. That way, I can easily change the signature for type variable `Arr` in `myArr` to `Iterable<T>`, and this can also be used on other builtin/custom classes like `Set<T>` that implements the Iterable Protocol. Right now the best I could do is to have the user specify their desired return type as a generic function variable.

```
class MyArray<T> extends Array<T> { }

declare const myArr: MyArray<number>;

const myArrMapped_ = myArr.map(x => x); // expected MyArray<number>, got number[]

// Which is understandable, since `Array.prototype.map`'s type signiture
// has no way to determine what is returned by `MyArray<T>[Symbol.species]`.
// However, if I were to implement my own `Array.prototype.map`, how can I
// obtain the typing of `MyArray<T>[Symbol.species]` so that it correctly
// returns MyArray<number> in the above example?

import { Expect, Equal } from '@type-challenges/utils';

declare function myMap<T, Arr extends T[], R>(arr: Arr, func: any): any; // myMap

const myArrMapped = myMap(myArr, (x: number) => x);

type test = Expect<Equal<typeof myArrMapped, MyArray<number>>> // how can I make this work?


// what I tried to get `MyArray[Symbol.species]`

type HasSpecies<Species> = {
    [Symbol.species]: Species;
}

// @ts-expect-error: apparently ts yells at me for doing this
class MyArray1<T> extends Array<T> {
    static get [Symbol.species]() { return MyArray1 }
}

const species1 = MyArray[Symbol.species];

type didnt_work = [
    MyArray<any>[Symbol.species],                                       // 'Symbol' only refers to a type, but is being used as a namespace here.
    MyArray<any>[Symbol['species']],                                    // 'Property 'species' does not exist on type 'Symbol'.
    MyArray<any>[typeof Symbol.species],                                // Type 'unique symbol' cannot be used as an index type.
    MyArray<any> extends HasSpecies<infer Species> ? Species : never,   // never
    typeof (MyArray[Symbol.species]),                                   // just doesn't work
    typeof species1,                                                    // apparently returns ArrayConstructor instead, and I must extract type from a variable
]

class MyArray2<T> extends Array<T> {
    static get species() { return MyArray1 }
}

type a = typeof Array[Symbol.species];
const species2 = MyArray1[Symbol.species];

type worked_but_not_the_way_i_wanted = [
    typeof MyArray2.species, // not Symbol.species,
    typeof species2,         // kindof worked, so far the best solution, but I don't think
                             // I'm able to get here inside the `myMap` function, and I have
                             // to suppress a ts error.
]

// suggestions:
// 1. allow symbol as index key after the typeof operator
//  
// 2. there could be a `prototypeof` operator or a intrinsic `PrototypeOf<T>` type
//
// that way I could declare function `myMap` as this:
// function myMap<T, Arr extends T[], R>(arr: Arr, func: (x: T) => R): ReturnType<(prototypeof Arr)[Symbol['species']]>;
// or this
// function myMap<T, Arr extends T[], R>(arr: Arr, func: (x: T) => R): ReturnType<(PrototypeOf<Arr>)[Symbol['species']]>;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBBATss8A8AVAfNApgB4Au+AdgCYwpqa7QDe0AvgFCsX6hjL7TAB7MhGLQAtklQAuOJNoYyAVzEAjfMhwBudoOGiJNWGAAOx-BQD60ALzi5AOjEmAFIRt5CASk3QA9L4JCM2BSClkadAVlNQ0AGmgAcwFRJVV1AG0AXXZ-aAB1AAsAS2AC6CKYRUp1ETBKMBUQfHiIIrJgPgADCPh7Y2Rk5PgzRxNOgHIYYmG+VoSyIuJFXlZcgshoMgFoAHd0aGJtzlJkMTa+HfXRCuheJeQyc2gVeGhOhB7sHHSAZXhVAQgewQYJFfAQTKdeyrAIACQEO3wADd1PEigAzaAASV26j4h3KYmMTTE5H0rwRZDePT6A0O0xGTmMnXiBQR-Dq2Jh0AEKmIYDaBwK+OGbQSPMx7zkkVwv3+KkBwNB4Mh0Ag22IV3KokEqC4xBA8G5d2WwnCqEiqRieEFmr4DQEKMCYCJTQA-OwikSBMhREwAKJBfXxf0AR0UYBALGg6IGYmg4wAAgz8ABaUqRppkBLg3yKYhFEAQcbaDhccC8GNVEJFIR2IzGbDxGiBUiUGBYLLxABKOGcPGQMho8XR1ZkdXgnnHZHgPlyEgbOiEIjshhMZjCtgXLgMqHirhkVvUnnc0C8pZTB3BolsgeCxAwYYjIAwKYEmN3yAbG-iHwtmCPDQcDwNZ2WATkcScABrfFihgHYfSgj0cgCS4wFEHFiGQMEwgJHNRClHo5QBIEQS4MEIU6dhL1hSAfmVCAMHo8jwTwWwGFYaAuOgYiFVIhjMhkZjgAo7Q2G5ZMIFTIh72k1AfXHUweDJQ0DhgeB8BAItoHQ8Q+HRH1oAoAQxSFCpWG4KBzVoABGL5W3IKhoE+egOO4tV+QLYBEnwUReMVMiRJVZwTyYE0Hms9AbJYVhxMvCgigoMhiAsBDkCgmweM47i-3kCdvj+EilRYiF4nc8qKsqqqqtycZCr48YeTIVTeHRGoDm2MADhmeIVHzcoYDUUzFAgJ4Ni6sgXXBYwwA6aBhV4aF3NyyJ8vSN9MXqgKBLK6q9v23IsBmBMqiKcNZnlQFGvAsgtlENRoBGsaYE5NpODcFMlpy6VMHyhz22gWiIGEiiMDaNrkGgEHWOgN0oYY6BD2RVFuNyR4UWQbKuI26BnBW+B-P4krMk8Xb9vJrjcgAKxG0RjPBMhxlENKoNYbILPAKz8YAJnsog2ycly8Dc7jai8nzRECiiQsYW5fNNSL4Gitg4uOlnzAsPqUruiw7VS9ALCKfXkqeWx0ix7qzHfRXueKoKIHiNHkihy6ift2I2dYIA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you dont have to specify any `static` properties, because then you have to implement them all.

Since you want to override some of `Array.prototype` methods, I think it is better to type only those methods which you are interested in.

```js
import { Expect, Equal } from '@type-challenges/utils';

class MyArray<T> extends Array<T> {

    override map<U>(callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: MyArray<T>) => U, thisArg?: any): MyArray<U> {
        return []
    }
}

const instance = new MyArray<number>()

const result = instance.map((elem) => elem * 2)


type test = Expect<Equal<typeof result, MyArray<number>>> // ok
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgUQB5gKYGMYBoUCOArgIYA2cAvnAGZQQhwDkAAjAJ6YC0WAFuWQwA7AOYYAzgHoiMYGXFMA3AChlWMiXHi4AWXYBBKFBLsAPABUAfHAyoYwgCbbDxs1cSq4XuBABuGI2AHDDgQEjBTAFVLAAosAQAjEiwAaxohAC44GN9yIgws83xgIWDULKEiEASA-BIjEyy9FxMLSwBKOABea0j8GF5gcUMRAH4skiF2dqaDBrNoj29luCgMGCIoITgAbQBdZWXKZWO1CCFxeBLLyawQrrghDAB3XTnXU0rqgNj21SxzpdVhIiGR4A9rjBbhgAHRhMAxGIYQQgTo9GwouAAKjgACY-soOJg4PYgQ80JgcKZkMRyKYiRgIDRgeJQXg3i0zF8alBLHy4JJJD4UsogA)

The problem is that `Symbol.species` is static property
hence there is no way to access it from instance.
See [source code](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/663b19fe4a7c4d4ddaa61aedadd28da06acd27b6/lib/lib.es2015.symbol.wellknown.d.ts#L313)

Consider next example:

```js
type Keys = {
    [P in keyof SetConstructor]:P
}
// type Keys = {
//     readonly prototype: "prototype";
//     readonly [Symbol.species]: typeof Symbol.species;
// }
```

And:

```js
type Keys = {
    [P in keyof Set<number>]:P
}
// type Keys = {
//     add: "add";
//     clear: "clear";
//     delete: "delete";
//     forEach: "forEach";
//     has: "has";
//     readonly size: "size";
//     entries: "entries";
//     keys: "keys";
//     values: "values";
//     [Symbol.iterator]: typeof Symbol.iterator;
//     readonly [Symbol.toStringTag]: typeof Symbol.toStringTag;
// }
```

So, `Symbol.species` is possible to infer only from `constructor`. What does it mean on practice?:

```js
const NOT_IMPLEMENTED = null as any;

type ClassType = new (...args: any[]) => any

// if Symbol.species] exists in T -  it is a COnstructor
type Species<T> = T extends {
    readonly [Symbol.species]: infer Constructor;
} ? Constructor : never

interface MyArray<T> {
    [Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<T>;

}

interface MyArrayConstructor {
    new(): any
    [Symbol.species]: MyArrayConstructor
}

declare var MyArray: MyArrayConstructor;

const builder = <T extends ClassType>(constructor_: T): Species<T> => NOT_IMPLEMENTED

const set = builder(Set) // SetConstructor
const array = builder(Array) // ArrayConstructor
const myArray = builder(MyArray) //  MyArrayConstructor


type Test1 = Species<typeof MyArray> // MyArrayConstructor
type Test2 = Species<typeof Set>     //  SetConstructor
type Test3 = Species<typeof Map>     //  MapConstructor
```

See this example:

```js
type GetPrototype<T> = T extends { prototype: infer Proto } ? Proto : never

const NOT_IMPLEMENTED = null as any;

type Species<T> = T extends {
    readonly [Symbol.species]: infer Constructor;
} ? Constructor : never

type IteratorElement<T extends Iterable<any>> = T extends {
    [Symbol.iterator](): Iterator<infer Elem>
} ? Elem : never

type Instance = InstanceType<SetConstructor> // Set<unknown>


function map<Elem extends Iterable<any>, Constructor extends Species<Elem> >(array: Elem, cb: (elem: IteratorElement<Elem>) => any): GetPrototype<Elem> {
    return NOT_IMPLEMENTED;
}

// GetPrototype<Elem> === never
// Constructor
const result = map(new Set<number>(), elem => elem + 2)
```

It is possible to infer instance of constructor but not vice versa when you have only instance

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Actually what I described above is close but not exactly my real use case. I wanted to implement a `map` function (as a separate function) that can accept any `Iterable<T>` instance, a function to map to, and it would return the result base on the `[Symbol.species]` field of the iterable object's prototype if one exists. Otherwise, I will fall back to using Array. That way using this map function on a `Set<T>` would return a `Set<R>` etc. I was wondering if typescript can perform this kind of inference at the type level.

Comment: Also, there seems to be no way to extract a static class member that uses a symbol as its key or to extract prototype typing information from a type of an instance. Which would be crucial to what I was trying to do above.